# Domain HTTPS Requests Error with NextJs/Express Server

Tags: node.js, express, http, next.js, https

I deployed my website yesterday on a VPS then I installed everything and it was working fine on the VPS IP but when i installed certbot on my domain I got this error :

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https:// mydomain.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an 
insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://vpsip:1005/check'. This request has been blocked; the 
content must be served over HTTPS.
```

i fixed the issue with this HTML tag :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />
```

but now I have a problem when I change my server IP inside **nextjs-config.js** from **http to https** I cannot **npm run build** because there is no server running on https , when I change it back to http the build run successfully but my website says that it cannot find https://vpsip:1005/check because the express server is running in http and the domain is on https and it needs everything to run on https , how can I fix this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey how did you installed certbot ?

You may need to update your express server to use the certificates to enable https.

Overall i will recommand to use a proxy like nginx to enable your https.

Comment: i installed certbot like this :

certbot --nginx -d domain.com -d www.domain.com

i am using nginx but how can i move the request from http to https in nginx ?

Comment: Certbot should have generated a file under /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
Basically you can start your nextjs/express server on local area to do so you bind it on 127.0.0.1 with the port you want eg 3000. Then you create a nginx config to redirect to it. If you want more detail you can add me on discord leone#9710